# How to append a text file line to a dbf table?

Tags: python, foxpro, dbf

I'm trying append a text file line into a dbf table. I have to append using a tuple or dictionary or something any help?

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'*.txt'):
        file = file.upper()
        strFileName = r"\****\****\\" + file

        f = open(strFileName,"r")
        data = f.readline()

    removedash = data.replace('|',' ')

    data_tuple = tuple(removedash)
    table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)              
    data_tuple = (removedash)
    table.append(data_tuple)
```

Type Error: data to append must be a tuple, dict, record, or template; not a <class 'str'>

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 attached the error

Comment: Have you tried appending a tuple, dict, record, or template, instead of a string?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Im opening a text file and appending the line in the text file. So Im not sure how I could do that

Comment: first you create tuple - `data_tuple = tuple(removedash)` but later you replace it with string `data_tuple = (removedash)`. Brackets don't create tuple - it needs `comma` to create tuple `data_tuple = (removedash,)` or even without brackets `data_tuple = removedash,`

Comment: I don't know how you keep data in database and what you have in line but if you used `|`  in line to separated elements which should be in separated columns in database then maybe you should use `data.split('|')` to create list with these elements - and eventaully convert to `tuple` like `tuple(data.split('|'))` - and this tuple you should add to database.

Comment: If you `print table` you'll get a list of field names -- how many are there?  If only one, then `table.append( (removedash, ) )` should work (notice the extra parens and the extra comma).  If you have more than one field then @furas has the right idea.